Intuition of F statistic calculations in 2-way random effects-, fixed effects- and mixed effects-ANOVA
I try to understand the logic behind the math of random, fixed and mixed effect models. So far I think I've understood that they are all based on the same mathematical model, e.g. $Y_{ijk} = µ + \alpha_{i} + \beta_j + \varepsilon_{ijk}$ for a two-way design. However, depending on whether the factors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are treated as fixed or random, the calculation of the F statistics for the single terms vary (cf. here). More over, for a random factor, the residuals are assumed to follow a normal distribution with constant variance around µ.
Now I'd like to understand the logic (intuition/idea) behind these different calculations. Could some of you (maybe visually?) explain why they are calculated in the way shown in the linked image? How are the MS for the interactions calculated?
Moreover, can the logic be generalized so that one could for instance also test the significance of factors in presence of additional factors or interactions?
Thanks a lot in advance!
